# React: Trying to render props that populate AFTER render

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs, response, render

In my React app, I want to render a prop value, but it does not exist until the props have been updated which occurs after the render is complete.

`this.props.users` is an object, so I use `Object.keys()` to translate into an array, and then map through the child elements using the keys to target them:

```
// ...
render() {
   return {
     <div className='users-list'>
        <h4>Users List</h4>
        {!isLoaded(users) ? '' :
           Object.keys(users).map( (key, i) => <p>{users[key].email}</p> )
        }
     </div>
   }
}
```

This works, but it took me a lot of hacking and adapting the code to get there. Is there a better/more eloquent way to go about this? Because I imagine this is really common case! Does the component lifecycle come into it?

Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You're doing it correctly.

Comment: I really don't see anything wrong with this. The code reads easily. I can tell that you only want to render users once they've loaded, and from the code I can tell that the users also won't necessarily appear on the first render. This is a pretty common thing to do in a react codebase

Comment: Ok. Well that's good to know :) I felt like defining the list beforehand and then rendering it might be better. But I tried that, and it obviously then tries to assign the `users` value to the variable before render, which at that point is `null`. Just wanted to be sure this wasn't poor practice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a default?

```
const users = this.props.users || {};
```

Using ES6 and destructuring:

```
const { users = {} } = this.props;
```